# .git file location using Bonobo

Tags: git, bonobo

I've searched and can't seem to find a coherent answer to what seems to be a simple question.  I've found a lot of incoherent answers so I'm going to try and ask this as clearly as possible for future readers:

In the Bonobo documentation [here](https://bonobogitserver.com/frequently-asked-questions/) it says:

"Copy the value in the Git Repository Location.
It should look like http://servername/projectname.git."

I just installed Bonobo and using the command prompt added a directory (let's call it "projectname") to the Repositories directory and a .git directory within that folder, I added a test file and committed it.  It shows in the Bonobo web interface list of repositories.  Everything seems fine.  I want to clone this repository.  There is no projectname.git file anywhere.

The questions are:

1. Where is the projectname.git file
   1b. Is it simply a combination of the file directory name and the .git directory name?
2. Was it not created because I created the repository in the command prompt instead of using the Bonobo web interface.
3. If it's not there now, do I need to create one?
   3b.  How?

Any help here would really be appreciated, I've only found surprisingly cryptic responses elsewhere when this question was asked very directly "where is the .git file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a "projectname.git file" anywhere, which is probably why you can't find it, and you can't find any sensible answer to the question either.

- There's a repository, which is in a subdirectory of the directory Bonobo has been told is where repositories are.  (You wouldn't expect there to be a .git directory in there, because it's usually a 'bare' repository, so you'd expect to see a config file and refs/objects/info/hooks directories.)  You would probably have found it easier to have created the repo using the web interface, then at least you could see what it looks like when Bonobo creates it.   If you do want to make it by hand, you can use `git init --bare` to make a repo without a .git directory, although I think Bonobo does actually work OK with non-bare repos.
- There is a URL which Bonobo uses to find the repository - that ends `.git`, which is probably why you're looking for a file with that sort of name - but *there is no file called that* - the URL is interpreted by the Bonobo application directly.  You can either work out the URL - it will look something like `http://myserver/projectname.git`, or you can click on the repository in the web interface to go to its details page, and Bonobo will show you what the URL should look like (if you take the latest '6.0' unreleased version from github, you'll even have a button to copy the URL to the clipboard.)

**A general point, which is nothing to do with Bonobo:**

Although there was a time many, many years ago, when most URLs did refer directly to files, that's long gone, and many are just instructions to a web application about what information you are reading or writing - you shouldn't expect, in general, that there will always be a real file in a filing system which corresponds to a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And thanks+ for the general point.  I was not aware that it is becoming more normalized to have web addresses pointed to what looks like a file where none exists.  I understood with PHP that what definitely appeared to be code in the URL didn't refer to a specific file.  With just a name with an extension I would have always assumed it was a file.  Not anymore, thanks for the info!

I went to the details as you suggested and the URL with the .git is there, and now that I know it doesn't actually refer to a file I can rest easy and proceed.